# I want to convert a jpg image into a byte array and send byte array as a command to a reader in java

Tags: java, image-processing

I am using this in my project. I want to convert an image(less then 5kb) to a byte array and then send it to a card, and wait for the response.
once I get the response, I want to change it into a byte array again without the response bit(i.e. 9000) and want the original image back

Comment: What's your concrete question?

Answer (score 1):

To convert an image to a byte array, you would do something like:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(img, "PNG", out); // or "JPG", or whatever
byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
```

To convert a byte array to an image:

```
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(in);
```

As for the card reader, It depends...